# CakePhp4 Implementing deprecated Controller::isAuthorized() with the new Authentication & Authorization plugins

Tags: authentication, authorization, cakephp-4.x

I'm looking how to to implement the deprecated `Controller::isAuthorized()` with the new `Authentication` & `Authorization` plugins but I could not find the way.

For example in the method `RequestPolicyInterface::canAccess()` called by the `RequestAuthorizationMiddleware` I could not get an instance of the current Controller.

Any idea ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Policies apply to, and receive resources, the request policy applies to requests, and will receive the current request object accordingly, additionally to the current identity which policies do always receive.

The specific signature for the `canAccess` method in this case is:

```
canAccess(\Authorization\IdentityInterface $identity, \Cake\Http\ServerRequest $request)
```

eg, the method will receive the current request in the second argument, and you can obtain the routing information from the request parameters::

```php
public function canAccess($identity, ServerRequest $request)
{
    if (
        !$request->getParam('plugin') &&
        !$request->getParam('prefix') &&
        $request->getParam('controller') === 'Articles'
    ) {
        return $identity->role->name === 'admin';
    }

    return true;
}
```

This would allow only users with the role `admin` to access to the (non-plugin/prefixed) `Articles` controller, and allow access to all other controller to anyone.

Note that you will *not* receive an instance of the controller, as that specific check is a) not made against a controller object but a request object, and b) happens before the controller is even instantiated.

See also

- **[Authorization Cookbook > Request Authorization Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/2/en/request-authorization-middleware.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's what I understood when I read the documentation.
But because of developer habits I was looking for a way to reproduce the old `Controller::isAuthorized()` way ...